# Using FontSquirrel @Font-Face Generator: font quite fuzzy in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, font-face

Mac Firefox (3.6.3). Font looks sharp in Chrome, Safari, IE8 (not as good as  other 2, but less fuzzy than Firefox). Any work arounds? How can I determine which of the source files Firefox is using? Can I force it in the CSS to choose something else?

Comment: Do you have a demonstration anywhere we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

Some fonts (especially free ones) are only designed to render in certain base sizes and can render oddly otherwise.  What looks pixelated at 16px might anti-alias cleanly at 17px.  Experiment by raising or lowering the `font-size` by a few pixels and see if you get better results.

Comment: Would that differ between Browsers?

Comment: Yes, it depends on which type of font the browser users, whether `.ttf`, `.otf`, `.eof`, `.svg` or other.